# How to create faces between parent objects?

Tags: faces, parent

I have two objects, and one is the parent of another. The reason of the parent relationship is that I want to apply different textures to each object. The two objects need to be bound, so I need to create faces between the two objects, but in edit mode I can only select the vertices of a single object. Can this be done? if not, what's the solution in my case? I need to separate the two objects somehow because I want to apply different textures to them.

Comment: I don't think you can create faces between different objects. You could use some sort of hack by creating curve between them and arraying one more mesh serving as "faces", but the place of joint will be visible.Try to join them and e.g. [apply different materials for those objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parenting the object, you need to join them if you're going to connect them, select both and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, doing so will make them two objects with separate meshes, you can now press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to Edit mode and work on vertices, edges and faces of both meshes.
You can still create separate textures, assign separate UVs to the same mesh.